# Spivak Calculus - Ch. 1 ex 5.8 : multiplication respects field ordering

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-explanation, ordered-fields

In Spivak's Calculus, Chapter 1 Question 5.8:

> Prove that, if $0 \leq a \lt b$ and $0 \leq c \lt d$, then $ac \lt bd$ using the following axioms:
>
> [image]
>   [image]

I have the following worked out:

**Theorem 1**

$$
\begin{align}
a \cdot 0 &= a \cdot 0 &\text{Identity} \tag{1.0} \\
a \cdot ( 0 + 0 ) &= a \cdot 0 &\text{P2} \tag{1.1} \\
a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 &= a \cdot 0 &\text{P9} \tag{1.2} \\
( a \cdot 0 + a \cdot 0 ) + (-a) \cdot 0 &= a \cdot 0 + (-a) \cdot 0 &\text{By Addition} \tag{1.3} \\
a \cdot 0 + \left[ a \cdot 0 + (-a) \cdot 0 \right] &= a \cdot 0 + (-a) \cdot 0 &\text{P1} \tag{1.4} \\
a \cdot 0 + 0 &= 0 &\text{P3} \tag{1.5} \\
a \cdot 0 &= 0 &\text{P2 QED} \tag{1.6} \\
\end{align}
$$

**Theorem 2**

$$
\begin{align}
& ac \lt bc &\text{Assume} \tag{2.0} \\
& 0 \lt bc - ac &\text{Addition of Inverse and P3} \tag{2.1} \\
& 0 \lt c \cdot (b - a) &\text{P9} \tag{2.2} \\
& c \cdot (b - a) \in P &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{2.3} \\
& ( b - a \in P ) \land ( c \in P ) &\text{P12} \tag{2.4} \\
& ( 0 \lt b - a ) \land ( 0 \lt c ) &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{2.5} \\
\therefore ( ac \lt bc ) \to & \left[ ( 0 \lt b - a ) \land ( 0 \lt c ) \right] \tag{2.6} \\
\\
&( 0 \lt b - a ) \land ( 0 \lt c ) &\text{Assume} \tag{2.7} \\
& ( b - a \in P ) \land ( c \in P ) &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{2.8} \\
& c \cdot (b - a) \in P &\text{P12} \tag{2.9} \\
& 0 \lt c \cdot (b - a) &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{2.10} \\
& 0 \lt bc - ac &\text{P9} \tag{2.11} \\
& ac \lt bc &\text{Addition of Inverse and P3} \tag{2.12} \\
\therefore ( a \lt b ) \land ( 0 \lt c ) \Leftrightarrow &( ac \lt bc ) &\text{2.6 and 2.12 QED} \tag{2.13} \\
\end{align}
$$

**Exercise 5.8**

$$
\begin{align}
\left[ ( 0 = a \lt b ) \land ( 0 = c \lt d ) \right] &\to ( ac = 0 ) &\text{Theorem 1} \tag{3.0} \\
\left[ ( 0 = a \lt b ) \land ( 0 = c \lt d ) \right] &\to ( b,d \in P ) &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{3.1} \\
( b,d \in P ) &\to (bd \in P ) &\text{P12} \tag{3.2} \\
( b,d \in P ) &\to ( 0 \lt bd ) &\text{Definition of Positive} \tag{3.3} \\
\left[ ( 0 = a \lt b ) \land ( 0 = c \lt d ) \right] &\to ( ac \lt bd ) &\text{Substitution of 3.0} \tag{3.4} \\
\end{align}
$$

Which gets me part of the way there, but I still need to show that the following is true:

$$
\begin{align}
\left[ ( 0 \lt a \lt b ) \land ( 0 \lt c \lt d ) \right] &\to ( ac \lt bd ) &\text{Substitution of 3.0} \tag{3.5} \\
\end{align}
$$

The answer key in the back of the book hints that I should apply Theorem 2 twice to something to show 3.5 is true--but I'm not seeing how.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Applying Theorem 2 twice, you have: $ac < bc$ and $bc = cb < db = bd$. Now all you need to show is that $x < y$ and $y < z$ implies $x < z$, if you haven't already.

Comment: @DavidWheeler - Got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Less sophisticate than your answer:

$$
(0\leq a < b),\:(0\leq c<d)
\\(b-a)\:\epsilon\: P,\: (d-c)\:\epsilon\:P\
$$
as P12 says, if two numbers are positive. then their product is also positive
$$
(b-a)(d-c)\:\epsilon\: P \\b\cdot d -c\cdot d - a\cdot d+a\cdot c
$$
after some formating:
$$\\
a\cdot c + b\cdot d - (a\cdot d + c\cdot d) > 0 \\
(a\cdot c - a\cdot d)+(b\cdot d-a\cdot c) > 0 \\
a\cdot (c-d)+d\cdot (b-a) > 0
$$
for the sum to be positive, both numbers have to be positive, that's where the double use of exercise IV comes.

Comment: There seem to be some changes that are made but not explained. The expansion of bd - **bc** - ad + ac is changed to bd - **cd** - ad + ac. The rearrangement to ac + bd - (ad + **bc**) is implicitly changed to ac + bd - (ad + **cd**) to get the second rearrangement. The rearrangement to (ac - ad) + (bd - **cd**) is changed to (ac - ad) + (bd - **ac**), which is implicitly changed to (ac - ad) + (bd - **ad**) to get the factored form. Why were these changes made?